# Cannot populate a DropDownList in EditItemTemplate using OnRowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, edititemtemplate

This is my code behind code. I want to populate the DropDownList once the user clicked edit but the DropDownList I'm getting is null. Why?

```
protected void SupportSchedule_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.CommandName == "EditRow") 
    {
        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((ImageButton) e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton) e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        SupportScheduleTable.EditIndex = rowIndex;
        shift.Enabled = true;
        resourcedate.Enabled = true;
        ListItemCollection c = db.fillList();

        DropDownList ddl1 = row.FindControl("ddlshiftmanager") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList ddl2 = row.FindControl("ddldispatcherone") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList ddl3 = row.FindControl("ddldispatchertwo") as DropDownList;

        if (c != null && ddl1 != null) 
        {
            ddl1.DataSource = c;
            ddl2.DataSource = c;
            ddl3.DataSource = c;
            ddl1.DataBind();
            ddl2.DataBind();
            ddl3.DataBind();
        }
        getSupportSchedule();
    } 
    else if (e.CommandName == "CancelUpdate")
    {
        //some codes here
    } else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow")
    {
        //some codes here
    }
}
```

//asp code

```
<asp:GridView ID="SupportScheduleTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" runat="server" OnRowCommand="SupportSchedule_RowCommand">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shift Manager">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlshiftmanager" runat="server" Width="99%"></asp:DropDownList>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shift_manager") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle Width="32%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="lbEdit" CssClass="btn" ImageUrl="~/Files/edit.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("support_schedule_id") %>' CommandName="EditRow" runat="server"></asp:ImageButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("support_schedule_id") %>' CommandName="UpdateRow" runat="server">Update</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("support_schedule_id") %>' CommandName="CancelUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="false">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle Width="2%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    //two dropdownlists before image button
  </Columns>
</GridView>
```

I just added the ImageButton here in the recent update but this is my original code that doesn't work.

Comment: You cast `e.CommandSource` to an `ImageButton` but I don't see an `ImageButton` anywhere on your GridView. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a SqlDataSource instead of adding the list items from the back 
and this is what I used to get the selected value of the DropDownList.

```
else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow")
{
    int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
    DropDownList ddlshift = (DropDownList)SupportScheduleTable.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddlshiftmanager");
    DropDownList ddlone = (DropDownList)SupportScheduleTable.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddldispatcherone");
    DropDownList ddltwo = (DropDownList)SupportScheduleTable.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddldispatchertwo");
    string manager = ddlshift.SelectedValue;
    string one = ddlone.SelectedValue;
    string two = ddltwo.SelectedValue;
    int supportID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    String sh = shift.Text;
    String date = resourcedate.Text;
    db.updateSS(supportID, sh, manager, one, two,date);
    SupportScheduleTable.EditIndex = -1;
    shift.Enabled = false;
    resourcedate.Enabled = false;
    getSupportSchedule();
}
```

Comment: Note that this works because the SqlDataSource binds for you on each PostBack. So you set the EditIndex, the GridView binds automatically via the SqlDataSource, then you have the controls you need when you finally click the update button.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is a correct way to handle the issue you are seeing. But, in case you didn't figure out the actual cause...

The `ImageButton` you click is in your `ItemTemplate`. The `DropDownList` you want to bind is in your `EditItemTemplate`. `lbEdit` exists when you *are not* in edit mode but `ddlshiftmanager` only exists when you *are*.

So, the fix is to put the GridView in edit mode. Notice that this is something you actually already started to do. You need to set the EditIndex, re-bind the GridView, then get the row again. You'll then have the row in edit mode. This row should now contain `ddlshiftmanager`.

```
protected void SupportSchedule_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.CommandName == "EditRow") 
    {
        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((ImageButton) e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;

        // Set the index to edit
        SupportScheduleTable.EditIndex = rowIndex;

        // Re-bind the GridView to put it in edit mode
        SupportScheduleTable.DataSource = /* your data source */
        SupportScheduleTable.DataBind();

        // Get the row at the index. The row will be the
        // row reflected in edit mode.
        GridViewRow editRow = SupportScheduleTable.Rows[rowIndex];

        // Find your DropDownLists in this edit row
        DropDownList ddl1 = editRow.FindControl("ddlshiftmanager") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList ddl2 = editRow.FindControl("ddldispatcherone") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList ddl3 = editRow.FindControl("ddldispatchertwo") as DropDownList;

        shift.Enabled = true;
        resourcedate.Enabled = true;
        ListItemCollection c = db.fillList();

        if (c != null && ddl1 != null) 
        {
            ddl1.DataSource = c;
            ddl2.DataSource = c;
            ddl3.DataSource = c;
            ddl1.DataBind();
            ddl2.DataBind();
            ddl3.DataBind();
        }
        getSupportSchedule();
    }

    // Everything else...

}
```

Comment: hi i tried using the first four rows of this code and i got the error " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." on the fourth line, why? :O

Comment: hi i tried using the first four rows of this code and i got the error " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." on the fourth line, why? :O @j.f.

Comment: Sorry, I think the issue may be that you need to set a DataSource before binding. If you set a breakpoint, my guess is that the rows collection doesn't contain any rows.

Comment: oh ok thanks! :) i thought it was gonna work without the datasource :)